# zooming buttons

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

How can I zoom in and zoom out with buttons I have added on an image in the `.nib` file? I can zoom the image, but the buttons are not shown in the run time on the simulator.

I use the following code for zooming:

```
i do what u say in the view did load and here is the code 
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.visiblePopTipViews = [NSMutableArray array];

    self.contents = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     // Rounded rect buttons
                     @"Play Ground", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                     @"HeadMaster", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                     @"Science Faculty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                     @"Accounting Faculty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                     @"Economy Faculty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                     @"Cultive Faculty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
                     @"Tourisim Faculty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:7],
                     @"Swimming Pool ", [NSNumber numberWithInt:8],
                     @"Medicine Faculty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:9],
                     @"Engeneering Faculty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                     @"IT Faculty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:11],
                     nil];

    // Array of (backgroundColor, textColor) pairs.
    // NSNull for either means leave as default.
    // A color scheme will be picked randomly per CMPopTipView.
    self.colorSchemes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNull null], [NSNull null], nil],
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor lightGrayColor], [NSNull null], nil],
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor lightGrayColor], [NSNull null], nil],
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor lightGrayColor], [UIColor darkTextColor], nil],
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor lightGrayColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil],
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor lightGrayColor], [NSNull null], nil],
                         nil];
     scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scroll.delegate = self;

     zoomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, scroll.contentSize.width, scroll.contentSize.height)];
    zoomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"]];
    scroll.contentSize = image.frame.size;


    UIButton *playGround = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [playGround addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [playGround setTitle:@"playGround" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    playGround.tag = 1 ; 
    playGround.frame = CGRectMake(290.0, 170.0, 80.0, 40.0);
    [image addSubview:playGround];

    UIButton *masterBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [masterBtn addTarget:self 
                  action:@selector(buttonAction:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [masterBtn setTitle:@"Presidency" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    masterBtn.tag = 2 ; 
    masterBtn.frame = CGRectMake(250.0, 270.0, 60.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:masterBtn];

    UIButton *scienceBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [scienceBtn addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [scienceBtn setTitle:@"science" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    scienceBtn.tag = 3;
    scienceBtn.frame = CGRectMake(300.0, 330.0, 50.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:scienceBtn];

    UIButton *accountingBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [accountingBtn addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(buttonAction:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [accountingBtn setTitle:@"Accounting" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    accountingBtn.tag = 4; 
    accountingBtn.frame = CGRectMake(340.0, 360.0, 50.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:accountingBtn];

    UIButton *economyBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [economyBtn addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [economyBtn setTitle:@"Economy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    economyBtn.tag = 5 ; 
    economyBtn.frame = CGRectMake(390.0, 390.0, 50.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:economyBtn];

    UIButton *cultiveBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [cultiveBtn addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [cultiveBtn setTitle:@"Cultive" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cultiveBtn.tag = 6 ; 
    cultiveBtn.frame = CGRectMake(440.0, 410.0, 50.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:cultiveBtn];

    UIButton *tourisimBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [tourisimBtn addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(buttonAction:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [tourisimBtn setTitle:@"tourisim" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    tourisimBtn.tag = 7 ; 
    tourisimBtn.frame = CGRectMake(480.0, 440.0, 50.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:tourisimBtn];

    UIButton *swimmingBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [swimmingBtn addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(buttonAction:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [swimmingBtn setTitle:@"swimming" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    swimmingBtn.tag = 8 ; 
    swimmingBtn.frame = CGRectMake(190.0, 400.0, 50.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:swimmingBtn];

    UIButton *medicineBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [medicineBtn addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(buttonAction:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [medicineBtn setTitle:@"medicine" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    medicineBtn.tag = 9; 
    medicineBtn.frame = CGRectMake(250.0, 420.0, 70.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:medicineBtn];

    UIButton *enegeneeringBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [enegeneeringBtn addTarget:self 
                        action:@selector(buttonAction:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [enegeneeringBtn setTitle:@"engeneering" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    enegeneeringBtn.tag = 10 ; 
    enegeneeringBtn.frame = CGRectMake(340.0, 460.0, 60.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:enegeneeringBtn];

    UIButton *itBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [itBtn addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(buttonAction:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [itBtn setTitle:@"It" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    itBtn.tag = 11 ; 
    itBtn.frame = CGRectMake(410.0, 500.0, 60.0, 30.0);
    [image addSubview:itBtn];

    [zoomView addSubview:image ] ;

    [scroll addSubview:zoomView];
   [scroll bringSubviewToFront:zoomView ] ; 
  // [self.view addSubview:scroll ] ;

   scroll.minimumZoomScale =scroll.frame.size.width / image.frame.size.width;
    scroll.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    [scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];
   self.view = scroll;
    [scroll release];
}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return image  ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loadView method is on your View Controller, isn't it? 
This method is called when the View Controller needs to load its view. If you added the buttons to the nib file, and this method is being called, then the buttons won't show up -- it's loading your code, not your nib.

What you should do is either add the UIScrollView as a subview, or set some more of this up in the nib file. 
If you do do it code, be sure to not override self.view, but add subviews to it. Do this in viewDidLoad, instead of loadView.

Doing that, your buttons should show up.

Comment: i make it like this way but i can't click on the buttons

Comment: You're adding UIButtons to a UIImageView...? That's interesting. You didn't write exactly what I had imagined you would, but it should do...

You should look up how to use loadView, viewDidLoad, and how to load from a nib. That'll make writing these things correctly a breeze.

If you just want to get it working, I think the reason you can't get the buttons is because they are _inside_ a UIImageView, which by default has userInteractionEnabled = NO, so none of the subviews (in this case, buttons) can be interacted with. Set image.userInteractionEnabled = YES and see what happens.

Comment: it finally worked with me  ,, the correct code ,, i must  add the image on the scroll[scroll addSubView : image] but before i define the buttons and i remove the view which i made     thnx 4 the hints in this situation we  must keep trying in the code to know what exactly worked